# Удаление дубликатов из std::vector

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Есть 3 вектора координат: `x_vect`, `y_vect`, `z_vect`. Они содержат координаты точек, т.е. координата одной i-ой точки - это (`x_vect[i]`, `y_vect[i]`, `z_vect[i]`). Но точки повторяются. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в итоге остались все точки, но без повторений. Необходимо убрать дубликаты точек.

Answer (score 10):

Можно использовать [множество](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), `std::set`:

**UPD**

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

std::set<Point> pointsSet;
```

**UPD2**

[Пример](https://gist.github.com/AlexDenisov/5177463) на пальцах.

Comment: не подскажите, как реализовать это в деле? т.е. как в set добавлять наюор из (x_vect[i], y_vect[i], z_vect[i]). с insert возникают проблемы

Comment: при этом x_vect[i], y_vect[i], z_vect[i] - vector<double>

Comment: Так ведь и смысл в структуре что бы не использовать vector ...

Comment: @1101_debian, пытался гуглить - не вышло, так что всё-таки спрошу. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие операторы в данном случае должны быть определены для класса Point, что бы set адекватно работал с ним?

Comment: @artyomdevyatov, обновил ответ.

Comment: Point p4(0, 3);
     .....
     points.insert(p4);

Точка p4 не добавится, потому что не определён оператор равенства. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Не добавится, но по другой причине =)
set использует `operator <`, а у меня закралась ошибка.

Обновил гист.

Comment: @1101_debian, а как set понимает, что элемент эквивалентен, а не больше других элементов? Ведь имея только оператор "<" нельзя точно определить, является элемент бОльшим или равным. Однако бОльшие элементы он добавляет, а равные пропускает. Как set их различает? Он же не умеет проверять эквивалентность Point'ов

Comment: Не знаю почему выбран именно такой способ, но он работает именно так.
Два элемента равны если первый элемент не меньше второго, и второй не меньше первого


   !(p1 < p2) && !(p2 < p1)

Comment: @1101_debian, ну так для без оператора < не обойтись, т.к. set устроен как дерево поиска. А если есть <, то == уже не нужен.

Comment: @dzhioev, спасибо, я уже почитал на эту тему :)

Comment: Вы на 100% уверены, что если есть `operator <`, то `operator =` можно не определять? Алгоритм поиска `std::set` же не знает, что вы определили только одну из операций корректно. Не пожалейте две строчки, определите и `operator =`, меньше геморроя будет.

Comment: Оператор == для set не нужен. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ . set использует только предикат с семантикой строгого оператора сравнения, который передан в шаблонном параметре Compare. Оператор < используется по умолчанию (через функтор less<T>).

Answer (score 10):

Строить set для удаления дубликатов не хорошо, так как set гораздо медленнее вектора, и потребляет порядочно больше памяти. Для такой простой задачи гораздо лучше просто отсортировать вектор. Известно, что из отсортированной последовательности удалить дубликаты легко, причём за линейное время. Более того, в STL для этого уже есть готовая функция unique.

```
//для вектора
#include <vector>
//для sort и unique
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x,y,z;
    Point(int x=0,int y=0,int z=0):x(x),y(y),z(z){}
};

//оператор меньше для sort
bool operator<(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
    return a.x<b.x || a.x==b.x && (a.y<b.y || a.y==b.y && a.z<b.z);
}
//оператор проверки на равенство для unique
bool operator==(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
    return a.x==b.x && a.y==b.y && a.z==b.z;
}

...

vector<Point> p;
...//как-то заполняем p
//сортируем
sort(p.begin(),p.end());
//и удаляем дубликаты
p.resize(unique(p.begin(),p.end())-p.begin());
//всё, теперь p содержит только уникальные точки
```

Comment: только сортировка работает за NlogN) (В среднем)

Answer (score 3):

Добавить методы для инициализации, что бы удобней было заполнять структуру.
И в чем именно у вас проблемы с insert ?

```
struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    Point(){ x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
    Point(int _x, int _y, int _z){ x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; }

}typedef Point;

std::set<Point> pointsSet;

for(;;){
   Point p(x,y,z);
   pointsSet.insert(p);
}
```

как то так ...

Comment: дело в том, что написана довольно крупная программа, в ней всё построено на vector, и данные, которые необходимо обработать таким образом тоже в vector

Comment: а разве в этом случае предикат сравнения не надо определить?..

Comment: Вадим Владимиров, в таком случае проблема в архитектуре системы, постарайтесь сделать рефакторинг, иначе в будущем может появиться много костылей для программы и костылей для костылей =)

Comment: а это прога для диплома, и это последняя проблема, которую надо решить, после её применения она отправится на свалку истории. Поэтому и прошу помочь именно в таком виде)

Comment: Ну тогда 2 вложенных цикла, и ищем такие же координаты, нашли - удаляем "Должен остаться только один!!"(с)
Но работать это будет не очень быстро

Comment: можно просто пробежать по массиву и закидывать ВСЕ значения в множество, в итоге там останутся только уникальные значения (мне прям стыдно такое писать =) )
<br/> **P.S.** что ж за ВУЗ, где дипломы таким образом пишутся? да и зачем писать такой диплом, который полетит "фтопку"? а что потенциальному работодателю показывать собираетесь? (простите) быдлокод с костылями на каждом шагу?.. но, дело Ваше...

Answer (score 2):

Если не хочется избавляться от векторов, то можно сделать так:

```
class Point {
    typedef std::vector<int> Coords;
public:
    Point(size_t index,
          const Coords& x,
          const Coords& y,
          const Coords& z)
        : index_(index),
          x_(x),
          y_(y),
          z_(z)
    {}

    bool operator<(const Point& other) const {
        return (x() < other.x())
               || (x() == other.x() && y() < other.y())
               || (x() == other.x() && y() == other.y() && z() < other.z());
    }

    int x() const {
        return x_[index_];
    }

    int y() const {
        return y_[index_];
    }

    int z() const {
        return z_[index_];
    }

private:
    size_t index_;
    const Coords& x_;
    const Coords& y_;
    const Coords& z_;
};

void removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& x,
                      std::vector<int>& y,
                      std::vector<int>& z)
{
    std::set<Point> points;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        points.insert(Point(i, x, y, z));
    }
    std::vector<int> newX, newY, newZ;
    for (std::set<Point>::const_iterator it = points.begin();
         it != points.end();
         ++it)
    {
        newX.push_back(it->x());
        newY.push_back(it->y());
        newZ.push_back(it->z());
    } 
    x.swap(newX);
    y.swap(newY);
    z.swap(newZ);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для правильной компиляции в ответе shurik'а и 1101_debian не хватает реализации оператора < для структуры. dzhioev исправил это, но написал ИМХО громоздко.

Попытаюсь дать решение попроще: =)

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <set>

struct Point {
    int x, y, z;
    Point( int _x, int _y, int _z )
      : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {}
    //
    bool operator< ( const Point& r ) const
    {
        return (x < r.x)
               || (x == r.x && y < r.y)
               || (x == r.x && y == r.y && z < r.z);
    }

};
// Функция уникализирует точки; результат - в uniq_points
void Unique( std::vector<int>& x_vect, std::vector<int>& y_vect, std::vector<int>& z_vect )
{
    std::set<Point> uniq_points;
    // Предполагается, что размерность векторов одинакова.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < x_vect.size(); ++i) {
        uniq_points.insert(Point(x_vect[i], y_vect[i], z_vect[i]));
    }
    // Печатаем уникальные точки
    std::set<Point>::const_iterator it = uniq_points.begin(), e = uniq_points.end();
    for (; it != e; ++it) {
        std::cout << "(" << it->x << "," << it->y << "," << it->z << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Заполняем векторы неуникальными точками.
    std::vector<int> x_vect, y_vect, z_vect;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        x_vect.push_back(i);
        y_vect.push_back(i);
        z_vect.push_back(i);
        // Создаём неуникальные точки
        x_vect.push_back(i);
        y_vect.push_back(i);
        z_vect.push_back(i);
    }
    // Уникализируем и выводим
    Unique(x_vect, y_vect, z_vect);
    return 0;
}
```

Итого: используйте функцию Unique для получения уникальных точек из общего набора и вывода их на экран.