# Удаление дубликатов из вектора без сортировки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector

Как правильно удалять дубликаты из вектора без сортировки, чтобы сохранить порядок объектов в векторе?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Удаление дубликатов из std::vector](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10157/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-stdvector)

Comment: Требования к оптимизации какие - по памяти, по скорости?

Comment: без требований.

Comment: @alexolut мой вопрос такой же но с условием

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Мой вариант решения. Мне кажется что он проще и понятнее чем ответ @gbg

```
[unordered_]set <type> s;
for (const auto &z : a)
    if (s.insert(a))
         out.push_back(a);
```

Мы просто проверяем, если ли элемент в сете, если нет - то это не дупликат и надо добавлять в ответ, иначе - дубликат. Остаётся 1 элемент из всех дубликатов.

Comment: да вполне и так можно использовать

Answer (score 3):

1. Создаете новый вектор на основе старого, но к элементам дописываете исходный индекс.
2. Сортируете промежуточный вектор по значению
3. Удаляете неуникальные элементы
4. Сортируете промежуточный вектор по индексу
5. Копируете результаты обратно

Comment: спасибо. красивое решение. но у gbg алгоритм попроще. если бы можно было выбирать несколько верных ответов я бы выбрал и этот ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Как один из вариантов — сначала перекачать все в `std::set`:

```
std::set<> s(a.begin(),a.end());
```

Потом грохнуть из массива (и одновременно из `set`) все, что не находится в `set`, причем быстрее это делать, создавая новый массив.

```
out.reserve(s.size);

for(const auto& i : input)
{
     const auto pos = s.find(i);
     if(pos != s.end())  // если мы ранее такое не встречали, тащим в выходной массив
     {
          out.push_back(i);
          s.erase(pos); // вот в чем цимес, из сета мы его убираем, и при новой встрече копировать не станем.
     }
}
```

Версия гораздо лучше (@pavel):

```
for (auto z: a) if (s.insert(z)) out.push_back(z)
```

Comment: Я понял из вопроса, что если айтем содержит дубликат - нужно грохать только дубликат, а не оба айтема вместе. Ваш алгоритм тотально все вычистит

Comment: @MalovVladimir, все нормально, если надо сохранить какой то из дубликатов то делаем это в алгоритме. я вопрос задавал в надежде что есть уже готовая функция

Comment: @perfect тогда ок!

Comment: Что-то не пойму как ваш алгоритм работает. В set же окажутся **все** элементы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov у нас разные взгляды на понятие "дубликат"
ДУБЛИКАТ - это копия элемента. скажем 1112223 -> 123
ДУБЛИКАТ - элемент, у которого есть хотя бы один повтор 1112223 -> 12
у вас - второй взгляд, у меня - первый. Такие дела.

Comment: @gbg почему вы считаете, что у меня второй взгляд?

Comment: @PavelMayorov это уже оффтопик, изучать, куда у меня мозговой шифер сдвинулся. Я добавил в ответ псевдокод.

Comment: @gbg вот теперь понятно. Осталось написать про удаление элемента из set в описании алгоритма.

Comment: @gbg зря код добавили, сейчас обломаются все те кому нужно оставлять один экземпляр дубликата с конца или середины ) первый вариант был самодостаточным.

Answer (score 2):

Сложность в том, что "правильно удалять" понятие неоднозначное. Все ранее предложенные ответы опираются на оптимизацию по времени, т.е. создание дополнительного контейнера, его сортировки (пусть и неявным образом) и дальше переброске в исходный вектор.

Но есть и другой вариант: не использовать другой контейнер, а просто бегать по имеющемуся и удалять всё одинаковые. Алгоритмическая сложность безусловно возрастет, но по памяти будет выигрыш.

Пример кода:

```
void dropDup(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for( auto base = v.begin(); base != v.end(); ++base )
    {
        for( auto it = base + 1; it != v.end(); )
        {
            if( *base == *it ) 
            {
                it = v.erase(it);
            }
            else
            {
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: согласен, но если быть честным то я этот вопрос задавал с надеждой на то что есть какая нибудь готовая функция из коробки, что то типа **unique без сортировки**, а там бы и оптимизация в комплекте была.

Comment: @perfect `std::unique` оптимален, т.к. использует только смежные элементы. Более сложные алгоритмы наверное реализованы в каких-то специализированных библиотеках. Но в `std::` таких нет.